# Detect changes @Input binding in angular

Tags: angular

I need to detect value changes in `@Input` binding angular and execute a function when the value is changed

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  ...
})
...
@Input() myValue

//detect myValue changes
```

```html
<my-comp [myValue]= "val"></my-comp>
```

I need to execute some code component class when `val` changes.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-ngonchanges

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ngOnChange` lifecycle hook in angular for advance features.

```js
export class MyCoponent implements OnChanges{

@Input() myValue

ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChange){

 //current value
 let currentVal= changes.myValue.currentValue
 // previouse value
 let prev = changes.previousValue
}
```

`ngOnChanges` function execute when any changes in `myValue`

Answer (score 10):

You could simply use `set` here, like this:

```js
_myvalue: any;
@Input() set myValue(value: any) {
    ... // Your code goes here
    this._myvalue = value;
}
```

Now, everytime you assign a value to `myValue` inside your template the setter is called and your code will be executed.

I hope that helps!